# how does this syntax works?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
erase: function(item){
        for (var i = this.length; i--;) {
            if (this[i] === item) this.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

How would  this  `(var i = this.length; i--;)` syntactic construct work?

Should there be three sections? What is it in this case?

from [here](https://github.com/theshock/atomjs/blob/master/atom-full-compiled.js).

Comment: Not really pertinent, but it's IMO a bad O(n**2) loop where a trivial O(n) solution exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It initializes `i` to `this.length`, and uses the condition check to also decrement it. When it gets to zero, which is a falsy value, the loop stops.

But note that because you decrement in the check, the loop starts at `this.length - 1` and ends at `0`. So it's equivalent to:

```
(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

But please refrain from using this kind of syntax, as its behavior is confusing - as you might have noticed.

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop in C-like languages consists of three parts:

> `for` (*initializer* `;` *condition* `;` *update*) `{ ... }`

The loop then gets transformed into the following (roughly) equivalent loop (there are differences, but not relevant here):

> *initializer*`;`
>   `while` (*condition*) `{`
>       `...`
>       *update*`;`
>   `}`

So the *initializer* part runs first; then the loop runs as long as the *condition* remains true and at the end of each iteration the *update* part runs. It doesn't have to be an increment but the most common form looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < something; i++) { ... }
```

But you can write whatever you want into those parts and you can also leave them blank if whatever you do within the loop suffices for the loop to run correctly and terminate. So in your case, since `i--` is an expression that also updates `i`, the loop just combines both *condition* and *update* into one and counts down.

Comment: Or not... `for (;;)` gives you an infinite loop. Yay!

Comment: +1 posting just before I started writing my own long answer.  Note that in JavaScript, all 3 parts are expressions (not that it makes much difference explanation-wise).

Comment: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ: Thanks, I updated it. And I know nearly nothing of JS, so I hope Andy will excuse my technical mistakes here :-)

Comment: Actually, you have been right calling it *increment*. At least it's like this in the specification. But I agree with NullUserExpection, the name is not necessarily useful.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, `i` will reach `0`, which is a false value, and this ends the loop.

More specifically, after several iterations:

- It will check `i` and get `1`
- `i` will be decremented and become `0`
- The loop will run with `i == 0`
- It will check `i` and get `0`
- `i` will be decremented and become `-1`
- The loop will end

Comment: The loop stops at `0`, but the post decrementing operator will leave `i` at `-1` after the `for` statement.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ And since this is JS, the variable `i` lives on out of the loop.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, I hold my ground. I didn't say (intend, more correctly) that the loop's halting condition was `i==-1`, I said that once the loop stops `i`'s value is -1, which is not what the first sentence implies. `i`'s value is irrelevant, what is relevant is the value evaluated at the condition, which is certainly not `i`'s value.

Comment: @davin I don't get where you are going with this. What causes the loop to stop is `i` getting to `0`. Because you are using a post-decrement, it only becomes `-1` *after* that. In the loop body, `i` is never `-1`

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, I was referring to the original wording (which even that I read a little hastily). Really not very important since the answer's been updated.